# Android and Pixels versus Device Metrics

Tags: android

I have a problem that is driving me nuts.

I had 4 functions that would resize images correcly throuhout UI using density (1.5) and width/height values reported back by views, bitmaps, screen etc.

This worked excellent on SG II. But on a HTC Wildfire which reports density 0.75 ... **some** images got about 25% too small visually on screen... But when I decided to override the density to 1.0 those images suddenly fit while other became crisp, but no longer sized as correctly... And it is driving me nuts...

I can only conlcude hat I am some places comparing apples to pears (pixels and DIPs), but I can not get my tests to fit with what I read, so in an effort to be 100% sure of some things:

...

Will I get pixels underneath here? or DIPs? :

```
int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
```

Suppose underneat is an imageview containing a bitmap. Pixels or DIPs?

```
int widthParent = view.getWidth();
```

Underneath is actually DIPs, right?

```
getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

...

Here is my code that is not working (this code is giving a bitmap that visually takes maybe 2/3s width where it should take 100%) If you check comments the pixels values are apparently correct, but end result is not correct:

```
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
  new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      mainLogo.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);                                                                 
      mainLogo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); // mainLogo = ImageView
      SharedCode.sharedUtilScaleImage_Width(mainLogo, false);              
    }
  }                        
);                                   

// ...

public static void sharedUtilScaleImage_Width(ImageView view, boolean tryBackground)
  {
    Drawable drawing = null;
    boolean useBackground = false;         
    if (drawing == null) {    
      drawing = view.getDrawable();
    }          
    if (drawing == null) {    
      if (tryBackground) {
        drawing = view.getBackground();
        useBackground = true;
      }
    }      
    if (drawing == null) {
      return; 
    }        
    if (!(drawing instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
      return; 
    }                      
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();
    if (bitmap == null) {
      return;
    }
    //--                               
    int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth(); // returns 770 (which is correct checking on disk)
    int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();                
    // float density = 1;
    // density = MicApp.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // 1.5          
    float widthScreen = MicApp.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; // returns 480              
    int widthParent = view.getWidth(); // returns 480, should be same as screen      
    //--
    float xScale = ( (float) widthParent / (float) bitmapWidth); 
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(xScale, xScale);
    //--
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, matrix, true);
    int bitmapWidth2 = scaledBitmap.getWidth(); // 480
    int bitmapHeight2 = scaledBitmap.getHeight();      
    //--          
    BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);          
    //--          
    if (useBackground) {
      LayoutParams layoutparams = new LayoutParams(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
      view.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
      view.setBackgroundDrawable(result);
    }
    else {
      view.setImageDrawable(result);
    }            
  }
```

Comment: Those values are all in pixels if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Them all? Sorry for asking so dumb, but yesterday I thought I had a good handle on it, but the results I am seeing on the HTC is making me doubt just about anything now :(

Comment: all of them are pixels, remember to use DPI instead of pixels to get similar results on all devices.

Comment: Bitmaps have a density that is applied on top of their pixel size so a 100x100 pixel image is not always drawn at 100x100 pixels but could be drawn downscaled to 75x75. Check those bitmap options, maybe they mess up your scaling.

Comment: @Raykud in my situation, I just want to e.g. resize a bitmap so it takes the full width. Essentially setting image view width equal to screen width and then resize the bitmap inside so it takes the full width. This, somehow, is failing on me now.

Comment: @zapl Thanks... I am looking at this now! Loading them with options "inScale" = false. I will return with my results! I *really* don't want Android to scale the images for me :)

Comment: I have posted my full code I am using. I have commented out my densiy usage which on SGII2 worked all places, but on HTC failed some solves (1.5 versus 0.75) since if I understand people correctly here, I should not need. (But I admit, I am confused)

Comment: try adding [`Bitmap#setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setDensity%28int%29) (should prevent any density based scaling done by `BitmapDrawable`), also consider switching `ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE` to just `CENTER` since that's not scaling.

Comment: @zapl I think you can make your last comment the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps between decoding an image and displaying it. Those steps are typically used to display images from resources at the correct scale. If you put an image just in `/res/drawable-mdpi/` but not in other folders it can still displayed at the correct size on devices with other densities.

If you want to load an image that is meant for `mdpi`(160dpi) on an `x-hdpi`(320dpi) device and want it to appear at the same size you'll need to double it's pixel size in effect. E.g. a 100x100 pixel image would need to be displayed at 200x200 pixels.

The places that are involved in scaling are

- Decoding the image (see e.g. [`BitmapFactory.Options#inDensity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inDensity)). `BitmapFactory` could already decode a 100x100 png image into a 200x200 image.
- The `Bitmap`'s own density. This is a property of every bitmap and it is used to store for what density an image is meant. If `BitmapFactory` would decode the 100x100 mdpi image to 200x200 already that densitiy would essentially say "I'm x-hdpi". You could also disable scaling while decoding and would get a 100x100 image with mdpi density. Displaying that image would require drawing the images scaled at 2x.
- The `BitmapDrawable`'s target density which is generally the device's density. If a `BitmapDrawable` has to draw a `Bitmap` where densities don't match it will draw a scaled version.

Code from `BitmapDrawable`, `mTargetDensity` should be device density.

```
private void computeBitmapSize() {
    mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getScaledWidth(mTargetDensity);
    mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getScaledHeight(mTargetDensity);
}
```

And relevant pieces from `Bitmap`, `mDensity` is the bitmap's density

```
public int getScaledWidth(int targetDensity) {
    return scaleFromDensity(getWidth(), mDensity, targetDensity);
}

static public int scaleFromDensity(int size, int sdensity, int tdensity) {
    if (sdensity == DENSITY_NONE || sdensity == tdensity) {
        return size;
    }
    
    // Scale by tdensity / sdensity, rounding up.
    return ((size * tdensity) + (sdensity >> 1)) / sdensity;
}
```

- Scaling options of e.g. `ImageView`. If you want to display an `ImageDrawable` that represents an image that is (due to scaling or actually) 200x200 px inside an `ImageView` that is actually 400x300 px on the screen you need to scale the image again.

Using `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE` would draw the image at 200x200 px because `CENTER_INSIDE` is only scaling the image if it is larger than the view. `FIT_CENTER` would scale it up to 300x300. Just `CENTER` does not scale at all. It just centers.

`CENTER_INSIDE` + a 100x100 mdpi image from above would still draw it as 200x200px because of all the scaling factors stored in `BitmapDrawable` / `Bitmap`.

There are also several other places in the `BitmapFactory` > `Bitmap` > `BitmapDrawable` >  `ImageView` chain like the `BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap)` constructor that says

> *This constructor was deprecated in API level 4. Use BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) to ensure that the drawable has correctly set its target density.*

which could affect image scaling in undesired ways.

#### -> to prevent all the scaling

- decode without scaling
- Make sure your bitmap's density is either the current device density or simply `Bitmap#setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE)`
- Don't apply scaling while drawing via `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER`.